# How to get position of the Infragistics DockableControlPane

Tags: winforms, infragistics

Is there any way to get the location of the DockableControlPane Infragistics control?

I have DockableControlPane in WinForms application, when I move it, I need to get current position of the DockableControlPane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FloatingLocation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinDock.v15.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinDock.DockAreaPane~FloatingLocation.html) property of DockAreaPane. This returns or sets the location of the DockAreaPane when it is floating.